# LinkSnooper troubles on Windows

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, java

I'm trying to get LinkSnooper up and working on a Windows 7 machine to monitor the interaction between the Mathematica front end and MathLink. I'm facing great troubles following the instructions [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/util/LinkSnooper.html). Namely, my arguments to MLOpen are as follows:

```
-LinkMode Launch -LinkName "'C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Java/Windows-x86-64/javaw' -classpath \"C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar\" com.wolfram.jlink.util.LinkSnooper -kernelname 'C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/mathkernel.exe'"
```

and when loading the kernel, a file system browser pops up and asks me to select a MathLink program to run. Anyone got this working on a windows machine and perhaps have some suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One problem is that your path to `javaw` is wrong (you forgot the `bin` dir). But that quoting style is very hard to make work, and possibly flat-out wrong (I swear that example in the documentation worked about nine years ago when I wrote it, but I cannot seem to make anything like it work now; my apologies).

The correct way is to invert your single and double quotes, meaning use a single quote around the whole outer -LinkName part, and then use unescaped double quotes for pathnames within it. Like this:

```
-LinkMode Launch -LinkName '"C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Java/Windows-x86-64/bin/javaw.exe" -classpath "C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar" com.wolfram.jlink.util.LinkSnooper -kernelname "C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/mathkernel.exe"'
```

Comment: Wow, finally I found this. I was wondering what is wrong. :) p.s. I had to use `-cp` instead of `-classpath` to make it work.

Comment: @Todd Unfortunately, this seems not to work on Windows 32 bits systemes with Mathematica 10, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66070/installing-linksnooper-on-windows/66465#66465).