# How to force the FrontEnd to add (Plus)

Tags: functions, front-end, evaluation

You need to set up the LinkSnooper to follow the steps from this question:

- [Installing LinkSnooper on Windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66465/5478)

---

So, if you have it set for a notebook or `$FrontEndSession` you can check that a `Button's` action in:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, {Button["+", FEPrivate`Set[x, 1]], Dynamic[x]}]
```

nicely changes `x` to `1` without calling the Kernel. However, a slightly complicated example needs Kernel's help:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, {Button["+", FEPrivate`Set[x, 1 + 1]], Dynamic[x]}]
```

There is no `Plus` in `` FEPrivate` `` context. But we know that the FrontEnd knows how to add:

```
DynamicModule[{x},
 {Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 20}], Style[1, FontSize -> Dynamic[x + 12]]}
]
```

The question is, how to force it to add, in the first/second example, without calling the Kernel.

---

Here is a hilarious trick (not useful in general):

```
DynamicModule[{x}, {Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 20}], Dynamic[11 + x]}]

DynamicModule[{x}, 
  {Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 20}], 
   Style[Dynamic@CurrentValue[FontSize], FontSize -> Dynamic[11 + x]]
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: not sure but I think that what the second kernel that always is started with newer versions might be used for?

Comment: @AlbertRetey my point is rather how to write `1+1` so that FE adds it by itself instead of sending to the main Kernel. And I don't care how it will be done :)

Comment: actually my hopes that this will be answered rest entirely on you

Comment: @AlbertRetey and others, the state of art is you can't do that. FE's kernel is limited and addition in mathematica is a complex task as it supports not only machine precision but exact numbers etc, not to mention arbitrary expressions. FE can't handle that so this path is closed for users. More or less what JF told me year ago or so, forgot to add this comment.

Comment: I think this got fixed some point: In my Mathematica 13.1 for ARM-64 Mac, LinkSnooper shows no communication in your first example.  I also noticed that the front end is a lot more responsive in general in more recent versions of Mathematica.  That means FE knows how to do arithmetic without K's help.  Maybe you know this already... still learning how this whole thing works...

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most serious answer, but you could use the following. Its most practical use is if you want a simple counter or something like that. It works with binary representations of numbers, where `True` means `1` and `False` means `0`. It is based on the concept of a [half adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Half_adder). Don't be fooled by the quasi informative comments that may give the impression that the code is understandable, in the end the code has become quite write-only.

```
nn = 2;

(*first argument (input) is the carry*)
(*output[[1]] is the value *)
(*output[[2,1]] is the carry *)
(*output[[2,2;;]] is the rest of the numbers that have to be added *)
retainingHalfAdd =
  Function @@
   Function[Null, Hold@{Xor[#, #2], {# && #2, ##3, False}}, HoldAll] @@
        Part @@@ Hold @@ ({Slot @@ {1}, #} & /@ Range[nn + 1]);

cyclerReducer = 
  List @@@
   Function@Evaluate@
     Join[
      Hold[#[[1, 2]]],
      Apply[Part,
       Hold@Evaluate@
         Append[{Slot @@ {1}, 2, #} & /@ Range[2, nn + 1], {#, 1, 1}]
       , {2}]
      ];

halfAddStep = cyclerReducer@{retainingHalfAdd[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &;
argListHeld =
  List @@@ Hold@Evaluate@
     Append[
      List @@@ Hold@Evaluate@
         Prepend[
          Part @@@ 
           Hold @@
            ({Slot @@ {1}, # } & /@ Range[nn]), 
          True],
      ConstantArray[False, nn + 1]
      ];

plusOne = 
  Part @@@ Function@Evaluate@
     Append[Nest[Unevaluated@halfAddStep /@ # &, argListHeld, nn + 1],
       2];

plusOneCode = 
  plusOne //.
   Join[
    Join @@ 
     OwnValues /@ 
      Unevaluated@{argListHeld, halfAddStep, cyclerReducer, listRHA, 
        retainingHalfAdd, nn}
    ,
    {And -> FEPrivate`And, Xor[x_, y_] :>  SameQ[SameQ[x, y], False]}
    ];
```

Here are some tests to see how `plusOne` can be used

```
testFu =
  FromDigits[Reverse@#, 2] &@
    Boole@Most@
      Nest[plusOne, OddQ /@ Reverse@IntegerDigits[#, 2, nn], #2] &;
plusOne[ConstantArray[False, nn]]
Nest[plusOne, ConstantArray[False, nn], 2^nn]
```

> ```
> {True,False,False}
> {False,False,True}
> ```

We can use the function like plus, but we will have to add `1` a lot of times.

```
testFu[#, #2] == Mod[# + #2, 2^nn] &[324232, 3445]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Using the following, we see that it can work completely in the Front End. We use `plusOneCode` instead of `plusOne`, because a few modifications were needed to make it work Front-End-only. Click the square a few times to toggle the colour. Uncomment the comment to see that we are counting using `x`.

```
ReleaseHold[
 ReplaceAll[#, 
    Join[OwnValues[
      plusOneCode], {startCount -> ConstantArray[False, nn + 1], 
      targetCount -> Append[ConstantArray[False, nn], True]}]] &@
  Hold@
   DynamicModule[{x, y = False},
    x = startCount;
    Column@
     {
      Graphics@
       {
        DynamicBox[If[y, RGBColor[1, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]],
        EventHandler[
         Rectangle[{0, 0}], "MouseDown" :> (  

           FEPrivate`Set[y, 
            SameQ[FEPrivate`Set[x, plusOneCode[x]], targetCount]]
           )

         ]
        }
      (*,
      Dynamic[Column@x]*)
      }
    ]
 ]
```

The following shows that doings things in the kernel is about 20x faster

```
feTimingFunc = (Function @@ Nest[plusOneCode /@ # &, Hold[#], 500]);
kerTimingFunc = (Function @@ Nest[plusOne /@ # &, Hold[#], 500]);
kerRes = kerTimingFunc[ConstantArray[False, nn + 1]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
ReleaseHold[
   Hold[
     feRes = FE`Evaluate@feTimingFunc[input]
     ] /. 
    Append[OwnValues[feTimingFunc], 
     input -> ConstantArray[False, nn + 1]]
   ] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.013697
> 0.210329
> ```

Somehow something breaks down if we nest the function more than `500` times, probably the front ends recursion limit is reached. Timings are quite acceptable compared to other delays when using `Dynamic`, in my opinion.