# How to style a cell depending on CellTags?

Tags: front-end, cells, stylesheet, style

Is there a way to create a style definition that reformats its background based on it's own tags?

The following doesn't work:

```
Cell[StyleData["MyInput"],
 Background -> If[CurrentValue[ThisCell[], CellTags]=="blue", Blue, Red]
]
Cell[BoxData["test"], "MyInput", CellTags->"blue"]
```

[image]

Comment: What is `ThisCell`? Shouldn't it be `EvaluationCell`? p.s. related: [version specific notebook styles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140965/5478)

Comment: @Kuba that's the question, it is undefined - and I don't think EvaluationCell is what is wanted

Comment: You said based on its own tags so I think it is. Or I am missing the point.

Comment: @Kuba Michael E2's answer works, I don't know why/how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Dynamic` and `SameQ` work for me:

```
Cell[StyleData["MyInput"],
 Background -> Dynamic[If[CurrentValue[CellTags]==="blue", Blue, Red]]
]
```

---

An alternative, from @Kuba:

```
Cell[StyleData["MyInput"],
 Background -> FEPrivate`If[CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[],
   CellTags]==="blue", RGBColor[0,0,1], Inherited]
 ]
```

or this, from @MB1965:

```
Cell[StyleData["MyInput"],
 Background -> FEPrivate`If[FEPrivate`SameQ[  
      FrontEnd`CurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[], CellTags],
      "blue"], 
    RGBColor[0,0,1],
    Inherited]
 ]
```

Comment: It isn't different enough to post a separate answer so maybe you can add it, if you want ofc. ``Background -> FEPrivate`If[CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellTags]==="red", RGBColor[1,0,0], Inherited]``

Comment: That works, but what is ThisCell[]?

Comment: @Kuba do you not need a ``FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[]`` and ``FrontEnd`CurrentValue`` there? I thought it would immediately evaluate like that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it might be worth making a note that if people are using the second programmatically  (e.g. with `SetOptions`) they'll want ``FEPrivate`SameQ[ FrontEnd`CurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[], CellTags], "blue"]``

Comment: @MB1965 Since the kernel does not know it ``FEPrivate`If`` is enough to hold it. I'd only be concerned whether FE knows it can evaluate it but it seems that inner content is parsed correctly. Don't know what is the rule of course.

Comment: @Kuba yeah I noticed that. It's interesting what one can do and what can't with the front-end evaluator. It seems if you set the styles by the kernel you need to use the unevaluated ``FrontEnd` `` and ``FEPrivate` `` forms but if you set the styles via the front-end that is't necessary.

Comment: @Kuba @MB1965 I have problems with the reliance on non-`Dynamic` heads.  Yes, it tends to get used a lot, and sometimes by us, but it's problematic for various reasons and not documented anywhere, so I wouldn't count on it surviving forever.  Wanting to avoid kernel round trips is a good thing, but a `Dynamic` head does that just fine, if you stick to the subset of symbols the FE knows.  And the FE *does* know ``System`If``, ``System`CurrentValue``, and ``System`SameQ``.  It does not know color names, though, so the usage of `RGBColor` is entirely appropriate here.

Comment: If `EvaluationCell[]` is not used, then there's a possibility that the `CurrentValue` will go wrong if you apply the style at the `StyleBox` level.  This is *supposed* to work...i.e., it should know that `CellTags` makes no sense at the `StyleBox` level and look upwards...but I know there were bugs fixed in this very recently by somebody in my group...either in 11.1 or in the current development version.

Comment: @JohnFultz Thanks for the tip, I now must leverage what is more problematic, that or having "Enable dynamic updating" popup for notebooks that aren't trusted by default, don't contain Dynamic itself but use this shared stylesheet.

Comment: @JohnFultz also tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets rather encourages skipping Dynamic. I trust you more of course and that tutorial's section is not probably so well known but it would be nice to have a modern FrontEnd side programming tutorial. Do you think management will allocate time for that?

Comment: @Kuba, I see what you're referring to.  I'll file a bug report for myself to, at some point, go and clean up that tutorial.