# Disable blue spelling tooltip

Tags: front-end, customization, spellchecker

I've noticed that at least on Mac, *Mathematica* automatically displays the blue spelling tooltip on misspelled words, but actually there's a much nicer, more reliable and faster tooltip when one uses the right click.

[image: blue tooltip]
[image]

There are a lot of glitches with the blue tooltips and I'd gladly just disable them for spelling (not for syntax). How can I do it?

Comment: It is just a setting in the preferences of Mathematica. "Check spelling as you type".

Comment: @SHuisman I know about this, but this disables the nice "red wavy-underline" effect which indicates that a word needs fixing... so this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluating the following once should do the trick for you:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {SpellingOptions, 
   "AutoSpellCheckPopupDelay"}] = Infinity
```

Comment: Close, but it doesn't really disable the spellchecking tooltip which is visible by the time delay it takes for the right-click menu to appear (there's a significant hiccup before it appears on incorrectly spelled words).

Comment: @Ranza On Windows it seems to do the trick, no tooltip after evaluating the code.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I think you must have a rather fast machine, on mine I notice a significant lag when right-clicking. That being said I'll accept the question if no better solution is found.

Comment: @Ranza I checked the code at 11-old time Lenovo laptop with Windows 7 and Mathematica 12.0 installed. I do not think that the difference is due to machine's performance.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm seeing difference on Mac, maybe the implementations differ. If infinite time is set no execution should take place. Just to be sure - try going over a correctly spelled word as fast as you can and then right click, then do the same with a one that's misspelled. That's when I see a difference.

Comment: @Ranza there shouldn't be a platform difference, and I certainly cannot reproduce your reported behavior on my Mac.  Something else is happening here...

Comment: @ihojnicki, @AlexeyPopkov This is weird indeed, [I've made a gif to show you what is happening in my case](https://imgur.com/FrY5rBb) (red blink indicates a right click). You might argue that this is a regular dictionary lookup, but this lag only occurs in MMA... Do you know how to investigate what is being run when I right click? Perhaps somehow inject the `Trace` command?

Comment: @Ranza `Trace` is for tracing evaluation in the Kernel, I don't know an analog for the FrontEnd (but would like to know if it exists).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov and Ranza, the LinkSnooper is the only thing available, won't show FE specific actions but if the delay is caused by FE-K communication then you will be able to pin point it.

Comment: Thanks Kuba, always nice to learn some new things! Following this [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66070/how-to-set-up-linksnooper-for-monitoring-frontend-kernel-communication) I have not seen any output when right clicking with finite and infinite `AutoSpellCheckPopupDelay`. I've also checked `ContextMenus.tr` and when I disable `MenuListSpellingSuggestions` MenuItem the delay decreases by 60-70%, so I guess... that I should get a new mac and stop whining, as the lookup appears to take some time.